# How to remove overlapping geometry in a complex object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I have this house consisting of many different overlapping meshes. So is there any simple way how to remove overlapping faces? I've tried booltool but it simply doesn't work properly with that many meshes
[image]

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: I'm trying to import this model into UE4 and I have issues with the lighting. UE says it is because of "UV Maps overlapping". I tried creating a lightmap manually but it doesn't solve the problem. While inspecting this lightmap I noticed that some of the faces still overlap with each other so it must be problem I raised above? And also generally people say that it is bad practice to overlap meshes with each other

Comment: You only have to fix the UVMap. If you create non-overlapping topology with the same geometry the vert count will be incredibly high. There are overlapping geometries in every videogame, it not cause any problem.